# Trouble with argv and char

Tags: c, char, argv

Since two hours, i'm trying to modify my program to give it arguments (argv) instead of a char.

So, here is my current code:

```
int i;
 char ret[81];
    *ret = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    { 
            ret[0] = '\0';
          strcat(ret,argv[i]);
    }
```

This code concatenate all args into a char, printf is returning the good same result as my old char argument, but not working in my code:

```
char test[] = "9...7....2...9..53.6..124..84...1.9.5.....8...31..4.....37..68..9..5.74147.......";
        solve(test); //working
        solve(ret); //not working
```

my app is launched like that:
./a.out "9...7...." "2...9..53" ".6..124.." "84...1.9." "5.....8.." ".31..4..." "..37..68." ".9..5.741" "47......."

Soooo, if anyone understand my problem i'll probably need some help :D

Comment: The description doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: `ret[0] = '\0';` move to loop out (instead `*ret = 1;`) and start `i = 1`

Comment: That was dumb from me, thanks alot...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY post an answer instead.

Comment: Care to elaborate? From the basis of your code, does it even print out anything for the user to see? But you say your code isn't working, but i don't think you're meant to put a * on ret when you're initializing it, and plus you're declared it as a character(char), and yet you assign it an integer(1). You need to change it to an int variable, and remove the asterisk then it might work

Comment: Yeah i pasted the wrong snippet, my bad.
Also, bluepix answered my question but posted it as a comment, i cant validate the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void solve(char *data){
    static const char *result = "9...7....2...9..53.6..124..84...1.9.5.....8...31..4.....37..68..9..5.74147.......";
    if(strcmp(result, data) == 0)
        printf("working\n");
    else
        printf("not working\n");
}

int main(int argc,  char *argv[]){
    int i, total_length = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
        total_length += strlen(argv[i]);
    }

    char ret[total_length + 1];

    ret[0] = '\0';
    for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
        strcat(ret, argv[i]);
    }
    char test[] = "9...7...."
                  "2...9..53"
                  ".6..124.."
                  "84...1.9."
                  "5.....8.."
                  ".31..4..."
                  "..37..68."
                  ".9..5.741"
                  "47.......";
    solve(test);
    solve(ret);

    return 0;
}
```